# window.parent in iframe from one subdomain to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, window.parent

I have a page which contains an iFrame which in turn contains a form. When this form is submitted, I need certain information to be returned to the parent.

Here's an example of the code I was trying to use to achieve this...

```
window.parent.$('#imagename').val("<?php echo $imagename; ?>");
```

The problem is that the page is on sub1.domain.com and the form (in the iframe) is at sub2.domain.com

I have ownership of both these subdomains so is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the domain in both parent page and iFrame using `document.domain='yourdomain.com` .
This will let you communicate from parent to iframe and vice versa without problems.  Browsers will treat them as same domain

See MDN Docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain